# How can I remove my button's border's color or/and control its behavior?

Tags: c#, wpf, button

**Expectation:**

Before Clicked -> Once Clicked -> After Release

[image] [image] [image]

**What is actually happening**:

Before Clicked -> Once Clicked -> After Release

[image] [image] [image]

So the border of the button stays green till the user presses another button (the other button gets green). How can I override that behavior? And if I can't then I want to remove the whole green-border thingy. I couldn't do that through the properties. Border thickness is `0` and no border brush on this button. So how can I do that? Please and thanks

**EDIT**: 
XAML

```
<Button x:Name="UpButton" Margin="0,5,5,0" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" PreviewMouseUp="UpButton_PreviewMouseUp" BorderThickness="0" >
    <StackPanel Height = "90" >
         <TextBlock x:Name="UpButtonText" Text="Up" FontSize="13" Width="18" Margin="0,2,0,4"/>
         <Image x:Name="UpButtonImage" Width="55" Source="/EZ3D;component/Resources/loc_up.png" Height="58"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Button>
```

Comment: Is the green border set through CSS?

Comment: @sam No. I think it is from a resource dictionary provided by dev express

Comment: Code behind or MVVM?

Comment: @step it is a MVVM but I didn't understand your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the image back to the original when mouse exits dimensions of image.

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_onmouseover

Example requiring jQuery:

```
<Button x:Name="UpButton" Margin="0,5,5,0" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" PreviewMouseUp="UpButton_PreviewMouseUp" BorderThickness="0" >
    <StackPanel Height = "90" >
         <TextBlock x:Name="UpButtonText" Text="Up" FontSize="13" Width="18" Margin="0,2,0,4"/>
         <Image x:Name="UpButtonImage" Width="55" Source="/EZ3D;component/Resources/loc_up.png" Height="58" onmouseout="javascript:$(\"[name^='UpButtonImage']\").attr(\"src\",\"/EZ3D;component/Resources/loc_up.png\");
```

});";"/>

Comment: Hi this behavior is not something related to the image. It is related to the button as a whole

Comment: In you question we asked if if the green is set through CSS.   In either case, the concept is the same:  use javascript onmmouse function to identify when the mouse has left the hover area of the button, and set the appropriate style.  You  would need to provide the code which sets the style but the property you likely want is 'border-style:none'